# Getting error while sending email - "There was an error sending this email"

Tags: marketing-cloud

for one user   we are getting the error "There was an error sending this email" when the user try to send emails from Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

The user has recently changed the password and after that onward this issue is coming . Tried removing cookies and used Incognito mode to access the application but still the user has the issue.

Is there any pointers for this error ?

Regards,
Anumol Antony

Comment: Could be several reasons therefore we need more informations. Are there any scripts inside the email? Is the user verified to send emails, i believe it does not have to do with caching problems.

Comment: The user us verified to send emails. This was working until she changed the password. There are no script in the email .

Comment: If there is a script, check if the field of this variable exists in the Data Extension.